# Add/Alter table columns dynamically using Spring

Tags: java, spring, yii

Is it possible to add database table columns dynamically in Spring framework?

By this I mean using the Spring DAO to alter table to add a new column without rebuild or compile.

I found this is possible in Yii (php) framework using [CDbMigration](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMigration).

Comment: Why do you need this capability?

Answer (score 1):

Spring is not really meant to do DB migration, you should take a look at tools like [FlyWay](http://flywaydb.org/), which will take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's better to implement this as part of a Maven life cycle, it is pro-grammatically possible to achieve the same using Spring framework. I wouldn't suggest the usage of DAO based approach for this.As mentioned by @Eric Citaire it's recommended to use frameworks like Flyway, Liquibase. Now both these frameworks work very well with Spring and have great integration.

In the Case of flyway the configuration that needs to be added is:

```
 <bean id="flyway" class="org.flywaydb.core.Flyway" depends-on="dataSource">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

Then from the code inject the flyway bean, simply access the migrate() which will use the scripts to migrate the db.

The same can be achieved in Liquibase.

In the Case of liquibase the configuration that needs to be added is:

```
<bean id="liquibase" class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
      <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:db-changelog.xml" />
      <property name="contexts" value="dev" />
 </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring DAO? No, DAO is `Data Access Object`, you need something like `Structure Access Object` that **does not exists** (and may never will).